# Enabling IAM Authentication for an existing RDS instance. What happens to current users?

Tags: amazon-rds

I understand we can enable IAM DB Authentication for RDS at anytime. If I were to do so, what happens to existing users who are connecting to RDS using traditional username/passwords? do they get impacted?

Answer (score 0):

There will be absolutely no impact since when you connect to RDS via IAM, you NEED to use a locally created user/role in the database.

And that role is simply granted with already existing iam role (like "rds_iam" for postgresql for example) and other priviledges you will grant to it.

I have done this with RDS Aurora postgresql from EKS pods and it work perfectly.

For your needs, you can find more information in the several AWS article that are available. Example:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam

Answer (score -1):

There will be no impact.
Those kinds of user, they use different plugins for authentication.

```
select distinct plugin from user;
+-------------------------+
| plugin                  |
+-------------------------+
| mysql_native_password   |
| AWSAuthenticationPlugin |
+-------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).